# Auto select checkboxes from data within Form Array

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, checkbox

I have a list of skills which is fetched from the DB like so:

```
  <div class="uk-margin">
  <div *ngFor="let data of skills">
    <div *ngFor="let skill of data.allSkills">
      <input type="checkbox"> {{skill}}<br>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**The above outputs:**

[image]

**My form modal looks like this:**

```
this.userForm = this._fb.group({
  name: ['', [Validators.required]],
  skills: this._fb.array([]),
});
```

I then fetch the checkbox values for the logged In user that they selected at some other time. As I am using `Reactive Forms` I `patch` the returned values from the DB for the user like so:

```
// Patch Skills
let ctrl = <FormArray>this.userForm.controls.skills;
  this.user.skills.forEach(item => {
    ctrl.push(new FormControl(item))
});

  // Patch Other things
   this.userForm.patchValue({
     name: this.user.name,
   });
```

If I `console.log(ctrl.controls);` I get the following:

```
I have a test
I have a nothing
```

How can I auto select the checkbox items that have been returned from the DB for that user *(so that "I have a nothing" & "I have a test" are auto checked)* and also update the `formArray` incase the user **checks** or **unchecks** values before sending it to the DB?

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML, use the `checked` property if your skill is contained in `ctrl.controls`

```
<div class="uk-margin">
  <div *ngFor="let data of skills">
    <div *ngFor="let skill of data.allSkills">
      <input type="checkbox" [checked]="ctrl.controls.includes(skill)"> {{skill}}<br>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this would help you!

Solution:

Component Code :

```
  let formArray: Array<any> = [];
  for (let skills of data.allSkills) {
    formArray.push(new FormControl(skills.value));          
  }
  let formGroup = {};
  this.fieldName = 'skillGroup'
  formGroup[this.fieldName] = this._formBuilder.array(formArray);

  this._fromGroup = this._formBuilder.group(formGroup)
```

Template :

**Edit:**

Live working URL: https://plnkr.co/edit/NC34MrQFbk4hNamOzsZF?p=preview